# When using OpenCV BOW, do I need to recalculate the vocabulary when adding images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I'm writing a function to create a BOW vocabulary from a set of several thousand images, then I'm planning on using this vocabulary to create a histogram for each image.

My question is... what happens when my set of images changes? Say for example I...

(a) start with a set of 5000 images,

(b) create the BOW vocabulary from this set, then

(c) go through the set and assign a histogram for each image based on that vocabulary (so I would end up with 5000 histograms).

Then... later... I add another 1000 images and want to create histograms for the 1000 new images.

Do I need to recreate the vocabulary for the whole 6000 images, and then recreate the histograms for the 6000 images?

Or can I just use the vocabulary that I got for the original 5000 to create histograms for the new 1000?

How does this affect the matching accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much agonizing and research and experimenting, I found the answer to this. It is better to use a vocabulary for the whole set of images, however it is possible to just create a fixed vocabulary and then create histograms using this vocabulary.

It would be useful to know if there are "reference vocabularies" out there that can be used. i.e. a set of vocabularies taken from well-distributed images that can be used as general classifiers.